# Special decision tree

Tags: python, dataframe

I have below dataset but its values are string. So when I want to train decision tree, these features should be transformed to num by label encoding.
 **How can I print these string on decision tree in visualization step and in rule export?**

```
feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4  target
low       low       medium    high      sick
low       high      medium    medium    sick
high      medium    low       high      health
...
```

and this is my code to create a decision tree:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(data)
encoded_data = le.transform(data) 
tree.fit(encoded_data, target)
```

Comment: Have you considered inserting all labels into a list (insert label if not already existing, so list has unique labels) ? When you need int values, find the item in the list and use its index. When you need string (label) from index, get item at index to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Print out mapping of classes:

```
list(le.classes_)
```

Do a reverse transform of labels to your categoricals:

```
list(le.inverse_transform(list_of_labels))
```

Docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#preprocessing-targets).

You can also use [pandas .factorize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
cat_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd']
encoded_data, mapping_index = pd.Series(cat_list).factorize()
```

Comment: Thanks @petezurich, but it want show real values not encoded values when plot decision tree, plot(tree), i tested have your proposed method.

Comment: @AHAD Ok. Then I suggest you provide the code with which you do the plotting.